# Spring. Passing string values from View to int/Integer parameters in Model

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am learning spring and I've encountered some strange behavior I can't explain.
Here I have simple class:

```
public class Customer {
    private Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Simple controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder){
        StringTrimmerEditor editor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class,editor);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String customerPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("customer",new Customer());
        return "customerPage";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/showConfirmation")
    public String customerConfirmation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result){
        System.out.println(customer.getLastName());
        if(result.hasErrors())
            return "customerPage";
        else
            return "customerConfirmation";
    }
}
```

And here's a part of customerPage.jsp:

```
<body>
    <form:form action="showConfirmation" modelAttribute="customer">
        Id: <form:input path="id"/>
        <form:errors path="id"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form:form>
</body>
```

I run it, leave id field empty and press Submit button.

If my Customer.id property is Integer, then I get following sequence of actions: initBinder method triggers and sets my empty string to null. Then the setterMethod triggers, sets id to null, all good.

But if Customer.id is int, then in the browser I get this: *NumberFormatException: For input string: ""*. 
The question is why input string in exception is just empty? Isn't initBinder should have set input string to null by this moment? I thought that the sequence always looks like this: @InitBinder methods→setter methods→validating settled values.

result→errors→source→cause→stackTrace:

```
"java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)"
"java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)"
"java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:989)"
"org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:211)"
"org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115)"
"org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)"
"org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402)"
"org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)"
"org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)"
"org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)"
"org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:453)"
"org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)"
"org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)"
"org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97)"
"org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:848)"
"org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:744)"
"org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:197)"
"org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:107)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:158)"
"org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:160)"
"org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)"
"org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)"
"org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)"
"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)"
"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)"
"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
"org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)"
"org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)"
"org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)"
"org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)"
"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)"
"org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)"
"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)"
"org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)"
"org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)"
"org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)"
"org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)"
"java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)"
"java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)"
"org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)"
"java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)"
```

Comment: Can you add stracktrace of the error? I think the problem is somewhere in StringTrimmerEditor. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringTrimmerEditor.java) how it works. Alternatively you can implement your own custom editor based on `PropertyEditorSupport`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for the `setAsText` in [CustomNumberEditor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomNumberEditor.java#L104) at the time of writing:

```
@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (this.allowEmpty && !StringUtils.hasText(text)) {
        // Treat empty String as null value.
        setValue(null);
    }
    else if (this.numberFormat != null) {
        // Use given NumberFormat for parsing text.
        setValue(NumberUtils.parseNumber(text, this.numberClass, this.numberFormat));
    }
    else {
        // Use default valueOf methods for parsing text.
        setValue(NumberUtils.parseNumber(text, this.numberClass));
    }
}
```

We see that if the `allowEmpty` property is **true** it will set the value as null when the text is null or an empty string. If the value is **false** it will just attempt to parse the number value from the String regardless, resulting in the error. Without digging further into the code it is reasonable that the `allowEmpty` flag is set to **false** presumably because an `int` is a primitive and can not be null. This may not seem like desirable behaviour but when an int is unassigned it will default to zero. You would prefer an exception to be thrown than an int set to 0 as this will just obscure errors.

Comment: But I only have `StringTrimmerEditor` in my `@InitBinder` method

Comment: None the less the stack trace shows: `org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115)`